# How to get extent of district when select by search nominatim

Tags: openlayers, extents, nominatim, ol-ext

I using `search nominatim` function from [ol-ext](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/search/map.control.searchnominatim.html)  library. I want to get `extent` from search results of county or city when selecting but I haven't found the solution yet.

This is my code:

**update**

```
// Current selection
var sLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 5,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgb(255,165,0)',
                width: 3
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255,165,0,.3)'
            })
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgb(255,165,0)',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255,165,0,.3)'
        })
    })
});
map.addLayer(sLayer);
// Set search control
searchNomina = new ol.control.SearchNominatim({
    reverse: true,
    polygon: true,  //include polygon
    // target: $("#asd > div").get(0),
    placeholder: 'Street name...',
    // className: "tim ol-unselectable ol-control",
    position: true  // Search, with priority to geo position
});
var requestData = searchNomina.requestData.bind(searchNomina);
searchNomina.requestData = function (e) {
    var data = requestData(e);
    data.countrycodes = 'en';
    return data;
};
map.addControl(searchNomina);
// Select feature when click
searchNomina.on('select', function (e) {
    // console.log(e);
    sLayer.getSource().clear();
    // Check
    if (e.search.geojson) {
        var fort = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        var parser = fort.readFeature(e.search.geojson, { dataProjection: "EPSG:4326", featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection() });
        sLayer.getSource().addFeature(parser);
        var view = map.getView();
        var resolution = view.getResolutionForExtent(fort.getGeometry().getExtent(), map.getSize());
        var zoom = view.getZoomForResolution(resolution);
        var center = ol.extent.getCenter(fort.getGeometry().getExtent());
        console.log(center, zoom, resolution, view);
        // redraw before zoom
        console.log('aaaa');
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('cccc');
            view.animate({
                center: center,
                zoom: Math.min(zoom, 16)
            });
        }, 100);
    } else {
        map.getView().animate({
            center: e.coordinate,
            zoom: Math.max(map.getView().getZoom(), 16)
        });
        var extentDist = sLayer.getSource().getExtent();
        console.log(extentDist);
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to include `polygon:: true,` in the `ol.control.SearchNominatim` options to get a polygon geometry returned.

Comment: Thanks Mike, it really helped me.